# Type ... is not a constructor function type

Tags: typescript

I wrote some code that works in the playground to create an intersection type to allow using either `new` to create a type, OR call the constructor instead. This works fine in the playground:

```
module Test {
    export interface IType<TType> {
        new (...args: any[]): TType;
    }

    export interface ICallableType<TInstance, TType extends IType<TInstance>> {
        (): TInstance;
        new (): TInstance;
    }

    class $MyObject extends Object { // ('Object' is here just as an example)
        static abc = 1;
        x = 1;
        y = 2;
    }

    function registerClass<TInstance, TType extends IType<TInstance>>(_type: TType)
    : ICallableType<TInstance, TType> & TType
    {
        return null;
    }

    export var MyObject = registerClass<$MyObject, typeof $MyObject>($MyObject);

    var o = MyObject();
    o.x = 1;

    export class $TestA extends MyObject {
        a = 3;
    }
    var TestA = registerClass<$TestA, typeof $TestA>($TestA);
    var a = TestA();

    export class $TestB extends TestA {
        b = 4;
    }
    var TestB = registerClass<$TestB, typeof $TestB>($TestB);
    var b = TestB();
}
```

([see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=module%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20IType%3CTType%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20TType%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20ICallableType%3CTInstance%2C%20TType%20extends%20IType%3CTInstance%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20()%3A%20TInstance%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20()%3A%20TInstance%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20%24MyObject%20extends%20Object%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20abc%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20y%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20registerClass%3CTInstance%2C%20TType%20extends%20IType%3CTInstance%3E%3E(_type%3A%20TType)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20ICallableType%3CTInstance%2C%20TType%3E%20%26%20TType%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20var%20MyObject%20%3D%20registerClass%3C%24MyObject%2C%20typeof%20%24MyObject%3E(%24MyObject)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20o%20%3D%20MyObject()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20o.x%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20%24TestA%20extends%20MyObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20%3D%203%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20TestA%20%3D%20registerClass%3C%24TestA%2C%20typeof%20%24TestA%3E(%24TestA)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20a%20%3D%20TestA()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20%24TestB%20extends%20TestA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%20%3D%204%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20TestB%20%3D%20registerClass%3C%24TestB%2C%20typeof%20%24TestB%3E(%24TestB)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20b%20%3D%20TestB()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20interface%20ICallableObject%3CT%3E%20%7B%20()%3A%20T%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20interface%20IObject%3CT%3E%20extends%20ObjectConstructor%2C%20ICallableObject%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20var%20%24Object%3A%20IObject%3CMyObject%3E%20%3D%20%3Cany%3EObject%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20class%20MyObject%20extends%20%24Object%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20var%20o%20%3D%20Object()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A))

Using VS 2017 with the latest updates this doesn't work at all.  `$TestA extends MyObject` fails with `Type ICallableType<TInstance, TType> & TType is not a constructor function`. Any ideas why?  It seems the playground has a bit older version, so was this a breaking change or something?

Comment: What is the version of TypeScript in VS 2017 ?

Comment: Why are you deriving classes from `Object`?

Comment: VS 2017 has v2.1.5 (preview has 2.2)

Comment: For the example - does it matter? Doesn't change the issue; just didn't feel like creating another class. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this works in Typescript v2.2, so it would seem the playground is at least v2.2. Visual Studio 2017 (v15.1 / 26403.7) is [stuck at Typescript v2.1.5 at the moment](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/03/27/typescripts-new-release-cadence/), but v2.2 is available in the [preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes).

If interested, callable class discussion was here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/183#issuecomment-296916884

Update: Keep in mind that ES6 classes have "specialize functions", and you will not be able to simply call a class constructor anymore.