# Type Function is not a function constructor type though Typescript version is above 4.7

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I changed typescript config to support decorators and then type from https://blog.logrocket.com/a-practical-guide-to-typescript-decorators/ :

```
const addFuelToRocket = (target: Function) => {
  return class extends target {
    fuel = 100
  }
}
```

In Vscode I get this Type Function error whereas according to [Type ... is not a constructor function type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601733/type-is-not-a-constructor-function-type) it shouldn't with version above 2.2, my typescript version in vscode at bottom is 4.7.3

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, the typescript version in VSCode is NOT the same as the typescript version of your project.

Comment: Why the typescript version in VSCode is NOT the same as the typescript version of your project ?

Comment: Because VSCode use TSServer to read your code, but your project uses the typescritp version in your package.json file to build your code. Sometimes the versions are aligned, sometimes VSCode uses the version in the package.json, but it is not an ABOSLUTE truth, just be aware of that !

Comment: @MGX OK I learned something then thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function needs a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) for you to extend it:

```
const addFuelToRocket = (target: { new(...args: any[]): any }) => {
  return class extends target {
    fuel = 100
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGRv2m)